# jQuery submit function not triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form

```
<form id="solicitud" action="ventas.php?content=nuevo" method="post">
...
</form>
```

Then I have to submit my submit using jQuery but I can't get it working

```
  $("#nombres").click(function(){
    alert('clicked');
    $("form").submit(function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

The alert function is called but my form isn't submited, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
$("#solicitud").submit();
```

instead of :

```
$("form").submit(function(event){ event.preventDefault(); });
```